# Android Studio moving project to another computer?

Tags: android

Does anyone one know how to move one project built using Android Studio to another computer?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? After all, a project is just a collection of files, so you should be able to move it as you move any other set of files.

Comment: I think the asker is concerned about Publisher keys and stuff.  I have that doubt too.  I have published my project and have saved the keys on some folder.  Now how to migrate so that nothing breaks.

Answer (score 11):

The folder is under C:\Users\YOU\AndroidStudioProjects\PROJECTNAME

You should be able to work on it on any computer with android studio installed.

No such thing as a stupid question. Thanks for asking!

Comment: Sorry, but this is not working if you have stored your project on another location e.g. like me on D:\Project\...

Answer (score 8):

Copy the project directory from source to destination machine. Then follow the steps.

1. Open Android Studio
2. Go to File - > Open
3. Browse to the project location.
4. Select build.gradle and open.

Android Studio will automatically make the necessary changes for the target machine and set up the project.

***NOTE :** It usually confuses the first timers, as after copying project files into  target machine, when you try to open the project, it considers it as a normal directory, not as android project.*

Answer (score 6):

Very simple..
Go to your project in AndroidStudioProjects, copy and paste it on pendrive/sdcard. Then plug it to another computer and open..

Comment: so i have google APIs in my project and a json file and a keystore. i moved all this over and now it has a new SHA1 fingerprint and none of the Google APIs work. @Raptor43

Answer (score 4):

I moved one project from PC to another with the same version of Android Studio (now for me is 2.3.3) and I have a failed to launch in emulator because the path of build test was not found. However the solution is simply:

> Build->Clean and Rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

I finally find the solution.
this is simple:

1- Go to your project folder, then open `gradle>wrapper>gradle-wrapper.properties` with note pad.
2- In last line, change your distribution URL to :`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip`(or each version of gradle you have.)
3- then go to Android studio and in project `build.gradle` and change your class path to latest version of gradle you have. `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'`
4- Go to app `gradle.build` and set `buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"`

Comment: Or, even better, use GitHub and clean and rebuild the whole project?

Answer (score 0):

When you are in Android Studio, you can sign in with your Google Account from top-right corner. After you log in to Android Studio, there are two options available:

1. Open Google Play Console
2. Open Google Developers Console

[image]

With Android Studio v4.1.1 there is not a feature available at this time such as synchronizing your all Android Studio apps depending on your e-mail address. This feature would be also very nice if you have different computers but only one project to work on, available. I believe Android Studio developer team will allow us to get our Google Account profile picture directly into Android Studio when we login. With the same feature, we can sync all our Android apps, I hope from the future.

Answer: No, you can't sync your apps with different Android Studio programs at this time (Dec, 2020)