# Android Studio moving project to other computer - SDK location differs

Tags: android, android-studio, copy, projects

the question is not as simple, as replied in 
[Android Studio moving project to another computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567931/android-studio-moving-project-to-another-computer)

Just copying folder results in my case in Studio could not find SDK location, rebuild does not help as errors could not find ...-appcompat-7 appear. Studio advices to load SDK, which I do not want to do as I already have SDK on that comp.

And all that just because computers have different user accounts - hence default SDK location path differs.

Is there safe simple way to copy and/or backup my work in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

If you use source control, an easy way might be to make sure all your changes are on the server, then clone the project on your second computer.

Comment: thank you for advice. I am only learning to use Github. I shared my project some days ago on Github. Now I choose commit changes in VCS it asks me for name and e-mail (not login and pasword). Why? I guess it's because it wants to commit locally, then how do I choose Github? P.S. I tried to share it again - it says project already on Github.

Answer (score 0):

copy the previous SDK to your new computer with project, And set location of new SDK and refresh the project

Comment: thank you. Not sure I got you correctly. Just to add to my issue is that now in project settings SDK location should be correct (as I remember now Studio asked me if I want to set other location when biulding the project first time). However, errors persist: see next comment

Comment: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.jar
         file:/C:/Users/PEE/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.pom

Comment: are you doing offline work? connect with internet so Android studio will automatically download the dependencies

Comment: Mozilla Firefox sees the internet, opens Github. Strange Studio works?

Comment: could you please reply to my comment to other answer - I'm trying to use Github to transfer project. By the way, looks I cannot send you message via stackoverflow...?

Answer (score 0):

What a program Android Studio! The issue I found is that in Gradle file appcompat was last digit different version, hence asking for download and looking on Studio server could not find old version.

I already raised ADV bug to Studio support sometime ago and got no response except that it was read.

So be it, hope somebody else will find out my answer here if faced with same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing the compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion from the build.gradle(module) of the project.